# Nginx: wildcard for the first folder

Tags: nginx

I'm struggling to create a Nginx rule for using a dynamic folder name.
I have 2 apps:

```
app1: /
app2: /resident
```

and they have URLs like:

```
app1:
  /dashboard
  /login

app2:
  /resident/dashboard
  /resident/login
```

So far, I managed to make Nginx work, sending `/` to `/var/www/app1` and `/resident` to `/var/www/app2`.
Now, we need to add the customer name in the URL. like this:

```
app1:
  /:customer/dashboard
  /:customer/login

app2: 
  /:customer/resident/dashboard
  /:customer/resident/login
```

The `:customer` will be a variable, and it should still going to the same filesystem folder:
`/:customer/` => `/var/www/app1` and `/:customer/resident` => `/var/www/app2`

I tried different approaches, different regex/orders. No success.

Comment: What did you try and what is the format of the `:customer` variable?

Comment: I tried different regex. `:customer` is a single word, no special chars

Comment: still would be helpful to see exactly what you tried, e.g., `location ~ ^/[a-z]+/dashboard$ {`, `location ~ ^/[a-z0-9]+/resident/(dashboard|login)$ {` etc.

Comment: @ldg can I use a wildcard for `dashboard|login`? it has a lot more pages there

Comment: sure - as long as you have enough specifics to make sure the different routes are distinct, you can update the regex however you like. You can use something like https://regex101.com/ to check against example paths.

Comment: also see: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/nginx-location-examples/